# Map implementation that keeps entries in the order of addition

Tags: java, collections

I need a key-value pair data structure which guarantees the retrieval of entries in the order in which they were added, much like `ArrayList` or `Vector` for just singular entries.  Think of it as an ArrayList that enables key-value pairs.  Keep in mind, the `TreeMap` will not do because the sorting does not go by the value of the key but by the time of insertion.  Is there a Java Collection that meets these requirements?  I browsed different `Map` implementations but couldn't find any that match.

I understand I can define my class that takes the key and the value and put it in an ArrayList but that is only option B to a class described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need a key-value pair data structure which guarantees the retrieval of entries in the order in which they were added,

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order.

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) ?

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order.

You can also look into the [Guava's ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) if it suits your purpose.

> An immutable, hash-based Map with **reliable user-specified iteration order. Does not permit null keys or values.**

Answer (score 0):

Use   `java.util.LinkedHashMap`  [Javadocs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

"This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order)"